# Silverstripe remove irrelevant has_one relationship fields in CMS tab

Tags: silverstripe

I have a DataObject called `ContentSection` that has 2 has_one relationships: to a page type `LandingPage` and another DataObject `Person`.

```
class ContentSection extends DataObject {
    protected static $has_one = array(
        'Person'        => 'Person',
        'LandingPage'   => 'LandingPage'
    );
}
```

Both LandingPage and Person define a has_many relationship to ContentSection.

```
class LandingPage extends Page {
    protected static $has_many = array(
        'ContentSections'   => 'ContentSection'
    );
}

class Person extends DataObject {
    protected static $has_many = array(
        'ContentSections'   => 'ContentSection'
    );
}
```

ContentSections are editable through the LandingPage and Person with the `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor` e.g.:

```
function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create(10);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content', new GridField('ContentSections', 'Content Sections', $this->ContentSections(), $config));
    return $fields;
}
```

My question is **how can you hide/remove irrelevant has_one fields in the CMS editor tab**? The Person and LandingPage relationship dropdown fields both display when you are editing a ContentSection, whether it is for a Person or LandingPage. I only want to show the relevant has_one relationship field. I've tried using dot notation on the has_many relationships:

```
class Person extends DataObject {
    protected static $has_many = array(
        'ContentSections'   => 'ContentSection.Person'
    );
}
```

I've also tried using the `removeFieldFromTab` method in the `getCMSFields` method of the `ContentSection` class, where I define the other CMS fields for the ContentSection:

```
$fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'Person');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `removeFieldFromTab` use the `removeByName` function. `removeFieldFromTab` will not work if there is no `'Root.Main'` tab.

Also we remove `PersonID`, not `Person`. `has_one` variables have `ID` appended to the end of their variable name.

```
function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->removeByName('PersonID');
    $fields->removeByName('LandingPageID');

    return $fields;
}
```

If you would like to selectively hide or display these fields you can put in some `if` statements in your `getCMSFields` function.

```
function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    if (!$this->PersonID) {
        $fields->removeByName('PersonID');
    }

    if (!$this->LandingPageID) {
        $fields->removeByName('LandingPageID');
    }

    return $fields;
}
```